# disable/enable Javascript event using Off and On, how to unbind and bind?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have built a menu item using Jquery.resposiveTabs.

I want to disable the mouseover event, when the screen size is small and re-enable it if the screen size is large.

This is my code:

```
$(window).load(function () {
    if (Modernizr.mq('(max-width: 991px)')) {  // ($(window).width() <= 991)  
        $('a.r-tabs-anchor').off('mouseover');
    }
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    if (Modernizr.mq('(min-width: 992px)')) {
        $('a.r-tabs-anchor').on('mouseover');
    }
    else if (Modernizr.mq('(max-width: 991px)')) { 
        $('a.r-tabs-anchor').off('mouseover');
    }
});
```

Everything works fine... Except, if I reduce the screen size the mouseover event is disabled and the event handler is disattached... when I call On() after Off(), it does not reattach the handler to the event. And I don't know How to find the event handler and reattach it?

This is my JavaScript initialization which attach mouseover event initially to Jquery.responsivetabs handler:

```
/*==========  Tabs Responsive ==========*/
function TabsResponsive(){
    if($('#tabs-responsive').length){
        $('#tabs-responsive').responsiveTabs({
            rotate: false,
            active:0,
            event: 'mouseover',
            startCollapsed: 'accordion',
            collapsible: 'accordion',
            animation: 'slide',
            duration:300,
            setHash: false
        });
    }
}
```

This is my html menu:

```
<li class="">
<div class="product-collateral" id="tabs-responsive">
    <ul class="nav-tab" id="classifiedMenu">
        <li><a href="#books" aria-controls="books" data-toggle="tab">Books</a></li>
        <li><a href="#sports" aria-controls="sports" data-toggle="tab">Sports</a></li>
    </ul>                                    
    <div id="classifiedContent" class="tab-content overflow-auto">
        <div class="tab-pane classified" id="books">
            <div class="text-content">
                <ul class="classified-links">
                    <li><a href="#">Children</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Comics</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Cookbooks</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>       

         <div class="tab-pane classified" id="sports">
            <div class="text-content">
                <ul class="classified-links">
                    <li><a href="#">Cycling</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Golf</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Football</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.off() is removing all event handlers from .on() - [jQuery .off() API](http://api.jquery.com/off/), so the event handlers set by your initialization of TabsResponsive no longer apply after .off() has been run.

You should just need to reinitialize TabsResponsive() in your resize function when min-width: 992px is true.

```
    $(window).resize(function () {
    if (Modernizr.mq('(min-width: 992px)')) {
        TabsResponsive(); //Reinitialize or use other method if provided by API
    }
    else if (Modernizr.mq('(max-width: 991px)')) { 
        $('a.r-tabs-anchor').off('mouseover');
    }
    });
```

Edit: Another thought, to prevent your TabsResponsive from constantly being rewritten when it doesn't need to be you might also include an additional condition for your ifs. This way if a user loads in at 1200px and resizes to 1000px you're not reinitializing. Something like,

```
var responsiveTabsCheck = true; 
$(window).load(function () {
    if (Modernizr.mq('(max-width: 991px)')) {  // ($(window).width() <= 991)  
        $('a.r-tabs-anchor').off('mouseover');
        responsiveTabsCheck = false;
    }
});

$(window).resize(function () {
    if (Modernizr.mq('(min-width: 992px)') && responsiveTabsCheck === false) {
        TabsResponsive(); //Reinitialize or use other method if provided by API
        responsiveTabsCheck = true;
    }
    else if (Modernizr.mq('(max-width: 991px)') && responsiveTabsCheck === true) { 
        $('a.r-tabs-anchor').off('mouseover');
        responsiveTabsCheck = false;
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this, so if I reinitialize the responsive tabs, I won't face any problem with them being reinitialized? it simply reinitialize the object from scratch?

Comment: That is what I expect would happen, reinitializing would rewrite the details in ResponsiveTabs(). If it doesn't you might also check the documentation to see if they include a method for removing and adding.

I also edited my answer, since reinitializing includes adding the "on('mouseover')" back, calling it yourself without any additional event handlers wont add anything.